# Поиск по фетчу Core Dat'ы с использованием fetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

В наличии `UITableView`, контент которой заполняется из `Core Data` при помощи `fetchedResultsController`'а:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    NSLog(@"fetchedResultsController");
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Client"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"agency_server_id == %@", agency.server_id];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName1Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName2Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName3Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"middlename" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortByName1Descriptor, sortByName2Descriptor, sortByName3Descriptor, nil];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

другие делегатские методы не реализованы так как таблица заполняется один раз, при входе во `viewController` и больше не меняется. Стоит задача реализовать поиск по контенту таблицы с отображением в таблице только результатов соответствующих значениям введенным в `searchBar`. Реализовываю метод:

```
   - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self reloadTableView];
}
```

и соответственно триггеруемый метод для отображения в таблице:

```
- (void)reloadTableView
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Client"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *filterPredicate;
    NSString *searchString = self.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"agency_server_id CONTAINS[cd] %@", agency.server_id]];
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"middlename CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
    filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName1Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName2Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName3Descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"middlename" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortByName1Descriptor, sortByName2Descriptor, sortByName3Descriptor, nil];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
        abort();
    };

    [self.clientsTableView reloadData];
}
```

который похож на `fetchedResultsController` но как видно имеется отличия в ограничении выборки. Проблема в том, что в таком виде вызов `-reloadTableView` дергает и сам `fetchedResultsController`, в результате фетч меняется в процессе ввода символов в `searchBar`. В таблице появляется все что вытянул `fetchedResultsController` и плюс все остальное что совпадает с содержимым `searchBar`а. Визуально: при вводе символов в поле поиска таблица не сокращает количество результатов а увеличивает.
**Вопрос:**
на каком этапе реализации поиска по уже фетченой выборке я делаю ошибку? Могу ли я как-то изменить вторичный фетч для поиска по уже полученным из первичного фетча результатам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос решился через составной предикат с использованием `+orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` и `+andPredicateWithSubpredicates:`:

```
NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstPredicate, secondPredicate, nil]];

NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:thirdPredicate, fourthPredicate, nil]];

NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:orPredicate, andPredicate, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

В таком виде через `AND` сохраняется результат предварительного фетча и через дополнительные `OR` происходит его фильтрация согласно критериям поиска

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите первый ответ, похоже ваша ситуация: [How to filter NSFetchedResultsController (CoreData) with UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll)

Comment: Указанный метод видимо работает, но удалось найти более простое решение для именно моего случая которое описал в ответе на вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18580245/1236726